# PHP: shell_exec(); not working identical to cmd? [WIN10 CMD]

Tags: php, cmd, ffmpeg, shell-exec

```
$MergeCommand = "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\ffmpeg-2021-02-20-git-51a9f487ae-full_build\\bin\\ffmpeg -i \"" . $path . $videoname . "\" -i \"" . $path . $audioname . "\" -c:v copy -c:a aac \"" . $path . $filename . "FINAL.mp4\"";
shell_exec($MergeCommand);
echo($MergeCommand);
```

Operating System: Windows 10

Sorry for the incredibly long and painful line I've provided.
From testing, I know that my code reaches the line `shell_exec($MergeCommand);`. 
It even echoes the value of $MergeCommand afterwards correctly. 

The problem is, as soon as it tries to execute $MergeCommand, nothing happens. It just **seems** to be going 
into the next line. What's supposed to happen, is that it merges a video file with an audio file. 
There is no output (*tried echoing the result of it*) and not any error message either. 
When using `exec($MergeCommand, $output, $retvalue);` to find out the return value, it returns 1. 
Though, if I copy the exact line that `echo($MergeCommand);` prints out, open a cmd, paste 
it in there and run it, it does exactly what It's supposed to do. 
Now I wonder, why does the same command work in a regular cmd, while it doesn't work when running 
it via `shell_exec();` or `exec();`??? 
It's not like `shell_exec();` doesn't work at all, I've come to the conclusion that it specifically 
happens when running that command. For example, `shell_exec("echo hello world");` works 
perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Seems `ffmpeg` filename extension is missing. Please try

```php
$MergeCommand = "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\ffmpeg-2021-02-20-git-51a9f487ae-full_build\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe -i \"" . $path . $videoname . "\" -i \"" . $path . $audioname . "\" -c:v copy -c:a aac \"" . $path . $filename . "FINAL.mp4\"";
shell_exec($MergeCommand);
echo($MergeCommand);
```

Comment: Sadly, it makes no difference. (Tried it)

Comment: Is `pclose(popen($MergeCommand, "r"));`  also fails?

Comment: Just tried it, the same thing as before. :(

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I've fixed it myself! 
I actually have no clue how that fixed it but it did.
I exchanged the first `shell_exec($strCmd);`(The command I 
run before $MergeCommand) with:

```
$output = null;
exec($strCmd, $output);
$output = implode(" ", $output);
```

and it works perfectly fine now. Seems like the first `shell_exec`
which executed the command successfully, blocked any other cmd execution
afterwards.